# Vim exit if no misspellings

Tags: vim

I have a batch of files that I'd like to spell check. When I loop through the files and open each one with this command:

```
vi -c 'set spell' -c 'normal ]s' $file
```

If the file does not have any misspellings, then I hear a beep, and I press `shift+z+z` to close the file and move onto the next one. If the file does have misspellings, then I have to decide if I want to correct the misspelling or add the word to the .spl file. I don't mind doing this part of the task, and I'd prefer to do this part rather than automatically adding each misspelled word to the .spl file, etc.

But I would like to better automate this, so that in the cases where there are no misspellings, the file automatically closes and moves onto the next one. This way if there are no misspellings in all of the batch of files, the for loop can run to completion without any user interaction.

So in order to do this, I need a way to determine if there are any misspellings in a file. How can I do this? Vim apparently knows how to do this because it beeps at me when there aren't any misspellings. And even better, what's the one-liner that I can use to replace the one-liner I'm using above that automatically exits vim when there are no misspellings in a file (and otherwise allows the user to attend to the misspelling(s) and then manually close the file)?

SOLUTION:

@Ingo Karkat's [SpellCheck](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3844) plugin worked perfectly for this task. The command `:XitOrSpellCheck` quits vim if there are no misspellings and otherwise does not quit and highlights the first misspelled word. So this plugin and this one command solves this problem exactly.

So after installing the SpellCheck plugin, the fix to the one-liner above is:

```
vi -c 'XitOrSpellCheck'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [SpellCheck plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3844) has commands like `:BDeleteUnlessSpellError`, `:WriteUnlessSpellError`, `:WriteDeleteUnlessSpellError`, and you can build your own such command easily.